# Sonarqube project dependency graph

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, dependency-graph, jdepend, sonarqube-plugin

I have an existing *Jenkins-Sonarqube* integration for daily sonar violation check using *SonarScanner*. Recently there was a discussion to **explore a Project Dependency Diagram_** on sonarqube, where I heard about JDepend plugin & tried integrating JDepend plugin in sonarqube and scanned the project.

Looking into projects Jdepend measures shows 0 however there are 82 packages found - please find screenshot below : -

[image: screenshot-1]

Can someone suggest on this as I am completely new with project dependency graph or
suggest any other plugin (open source/freeware) to achieve my requirement.

```
Sonarqube: 5.6.4  
JDepend: 1.1.1  
Jenkins: 2.89.4
```

Answer (score 0):

First of, as stated by the report, you are missing all package-info.java files. See the [Github Repo](https://github.com/willemsrb/sonar-jdepend-plugin) for more information, especially the [workaround for missing package-info.java files](https://github.com/willemsrb/sonar-jdepend-plugin/blob/master/WORKAROUNDS.md).

Secondly, you need to modify your Java quality profile to also include the jDepend rules. For this, go to Quality Profiles, clone the Sonar way rule set and than go to rules, filter for **repository** jDepend. Bulk edit to include jDepend rules.

In the end, you need to a new scan with the new rules and package-info.java files.